# SharePoint Online: Find all site collections a user is a member of

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I`d like to find out which site collections a specific user is a member of.
Unfortunately, my PowerShell knowledge is still very limited.

Here's what I've come up with so far but it's extremly slow and doesn`t return the results I want to get.

```
Get-SPOSite | ForEach-Object {Get-SPOUser -Site https://contoso.sharepoint.com/ -Limit All | Where-Object {$_.LoginName -eq "user@contoso.com"}}
```

Unfortunately, the output shows the user (Display Name, Login Name, Groups) and not the different site collections the user in question is a member of.

I have the feeling that the cmdlets have to be interchanged, i.e.

```
Get-SPOUser -site https://contoso.sharepoint.com/ | ForEach-Object {Get-SPOSite    -Limit All | Where-Object {$_.LoginName -eq "usern@contoso.com"}}
```

However, this command runs but doesn`t end or give an error message.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Calling [`Get-SPOUser`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161389.aspx) with `-Limit All` will return every user on the site. Instead of getting that (potentially massive) collection of users and then filtering it to get the one user you want, why not surgically retrieve the one user you want in the first place by providing the `-LoginName` parameter?

```
Get-SPOUser -Site https://contoso.sharepoint.com -LoginName "user@contoso.com"
```

This should be significantly faster.

To perform that check across all site collections, instead of feeding it the `-Site` parameter manually, you can pipe the results from `Get-SPOSite` to a for-each loop and access each site through the `$_` token.

```
get-sposite | %{ $user = get-spouser -site $_ -loginName "user@contoso.com"; if($user.Groups.Count -gt 0){write-output $_.url ":" $user.Groups} }
```

*(Note that `%{ }` is a shorthand alias for `ForEach-Object{ }`.)*

The output from the above code is not the most beautifully formatted. For example, if the user is a member of multiple groups (let's call them Group One and Group Two), they'll show up on the same line with no spaces in between them,

e.g. `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/site : Group OneGroupTwo`

As a cleaner alternative, consider storing the results into an array of PowerShell objects like so:

```
$arr = @(); get-sposite | %{ $user = get-spouser -site $_ -loginName "user@contoso.com"; if($user.Groups.Count -gt 0){ $arr += new-object psobject -property @{site=$_.url; groups=$user.Groups} } }; $arr
```

That should give you results like this:

```
site                      groups
----                      ------
https://contoso.com       {Site Members}
https://contoso.com/site  {Group One, Group Two}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. This is very helpful and I can understand most of what`s going on.

I noticed that by using the ForEach-Object loop the output I get will also be an error message for every site collection the user is not a member of. I let it ran, gettings tons of error messages and at the very end I received the desired output. Furthermore, it also said that more results were found but were not returned.  Use '-Limit ALL' to return all possible results.

Is there a way to only show the desired results?

Thanks!